# Using an array in where clause with node-mysql

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, node-mysql

I want to do a query that would look like this :

```
"Select * FROM ... WHERE name in ?" which would be equal to 
"Select * FROM ... WHERE name in 'joe','william', ..."
```

Would there be a way to do something like that?

```
Model.query(query, array, function(err, result) {...});
```

I tried the following :

```
string = array.join("','")
Model.query(query, string, function(err, result) {...});
```

But then here is the result I have (the backslashes appear due to the single quotes):

```
Select * FROM ... WHERE name in \'joe\',\'william\',..."
```

Answer (score 2):

### Simple queries

As @Raphael mentioned, for simple queries you can use `Model.find()`, [relevant docs section](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/67545664138e7362640756dd97205142cc72cac9/query-methods.md#find-criteria-callback-).

### Queries with join

For queries involving joins, you can use `find.populate()`, [docs for populate](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/be0d2b7d0c4fbee9a6dcbe1fc7fe74981708e0ef/query.md#populate). Example:

```
Model.find().where({
  attr : [your array]
}).populate('association').exec(your callback);
```

### Very complicated queries

For more complicated queries where not even populate is enough you can indeed use `.query()` ([documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/67545664138e7362640756dd97205142cc72cac9/query-methods.md#find-criteria-callback-)) but I think you may have gotten the syntax wrong. The second argument is an array. Example:

```
var title = "The King's Speech";
Movie.query('SELECT * FROM movie WHERE title = $1', [title], function(err, results) {})
```

Comment: I tried the second way you described, but I would only get the first item of the list going into the SQL request

Comment: What code did you use? In your case I think you would either need `.query("Select * FROM ... WHERE name in $1, $2", ['joe', 'william' ], ...` or perhaps `.query("Select * FROM ... WHERE name in $1", [ ['joe', 'william'] ], ...`. I'm not 100% sure the second option works...

Comment: I tried to do something like that : `code.query("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name in ?", [list])` but that doesn't look possible. I wanted to do the same as that `Model.find().where({
  attr : [your array]
})` because it works, but you can't do complicated associations without loosing performance

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Waterline (it should be the case if your are creating a sails app) just do:

```
Model.find().where({
  attr : [your array]
}).exec(your callback);
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but in the case I have complicated joins in my query, I need to use a normal SQL query